# JavaScript no longer executes after page receives AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm doing an AJAX request which a PHP script receives and sends back a response. Before the request is made, my JavaScript code works perfectly, but after the response is received from the server, all JavaScript code becomes useless. The code below has been provided just to illustrate what happens, and it does so perfectly:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form method='post' action=''>
    <textarea cols='30' rows='5' name='test'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='ok' />
</form>
<div id='ajax-response'></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('textarea').click(function() {
        alert('ouch!');
});
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4){
        if ((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) || xhr.status == 304){
            document.getElementById('ajax-response').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        } else {
            alert("Request was unsuccessful: " + xhr.status);
        }
    }
}
$('form').submit(function(event) {
        if(typeof(FormData) != 'undefined') {
            var oform = this;
            event.preventDefault();
            xhr.open('post', '', false);
            xhr.send(new FormData(oform));
        }
});
```

**The PHP script to handle the AJAX request:**

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    echo "<form method='post' action=''>
    <textarea cols='30' rows='5' name='test2'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='ok' />
    </form>";
}
```

The response is received and a new form is added to the page. But before submitting the form, when you click on the textarea, the alert is thrown. When the request returns from the server, this does no longer work (The alert is just an example; actually no JavaScript code gets executed). I've been on this all day, a solution would make my day!

**Edit**
Doug's answer below solves my problem, but I think it is worth mentioning that I also found out, thanks to gengkev's comment below this question, that using `innerHTML` removes not only the content of the element on which it is used but other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content. As a result, the code I put above also works well when I replace the line having the `innerHTML` property with:

```
$('#ajax-response')append(xhr.responseText);
```

Thanks for all your help, guys!

Comment: stop doing this on ajax success `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = xhr.responseText;` why are you replacing entire body of the page? May be put all <script> tags in <head> element and it wont get replaced when you update <body>.

Comment: thanks for the comment @Subin, actually, this code is just to show what happens. my `<script>` tag is in the head. I provided the code in the shortest way possible to illustrate what is happening.

Comment: Changing the `innerHTML` of any element (even appending with `+=`) will have the same effect as removing that element and its children from the DOM, and adding them back again. So any event listeners on the old elements will be removed! It's best to avoid changing innerHTML on things with an event handler.

Comment: May sound easy to you, but this should be more than a comment! Thanks a lot Gengkev, you helped me solve and understand the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've created the following JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zLAht/24/

This is what you wanted, correct?

The way your code was originally the Ajax request didn't replace the area on the submit, but based on your problem that sounds like the issue.

HTML

```
<body>
<div id='ajax-response'>
    <form method='post' action=''>
    <textarea cols='30' rows='5' name='test'></textarea>
    <input id='sub' type='button' value='ok' />
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('textarea').click(function() {alert('ouch!');});

$('#sub').click(function(event) {
            $.ajax({
        cache:false,
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/echo/html/',
         data: {
             html:"<form method='post' action=''><textarea cols='30' rows='5' name='test2'></textarea><input type='submit' value='ok' /></form>"
         },
         success: function(data) {
             $('#ajax-response').html(data);
             $('textarea').click(function() {alert('ouch!');});
         },
         error:function(error){
             alert('there was an error');  
         },
         dataType: 'html'
     });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work, Doug. I should have set up the script on JSFiddle, but then I wouldn't be able to make the AJAX request to a PHP script.

Comment: Use the Echo function of JSFiddle and you should be able to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Updated with JSFiddle. I cleaned up the code, and it seemed to work for me after re-applying the "ouch" after the replacing of text like my prior example referenced. See what I have on JSFiddle and if it mimics your situation. Oh, and I also changed the submit to a button to avoid having to fight with the submit action.

Answer (score 0):

I have got your point you need to bind the elements once you have done all these things. One way is to have Jquery and Use $.live function. You can bind elements in javascript as under

```
function live(eventType, elementId, cb) {
    document.addEventListener(eventType, function (event) {
        if (event.target.id === elementId) {
            cb.call(event.target, event);
        }
    });
}

live("click", "test", function (event) {




alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Hi, Ahmad. Web console and firebug don't show any errors. I don't think those lines have a problem because as I said, the code in those lines execute as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly:

when you replace html with AJAX, the new html requires you to re-add the event hoocks to them. So when you receive the AJAX response, just rerun your

```
$("form").submit(...)
```

hook.

Comment: Aroll605, I think I understand what you're saying, but how do I re-add the event hooks on the form?

Comment: Just rerun that piece of javascript. Put it into the function that is executed on `(xhr.readyState == 4) { // here }`, but *after* setting `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is event delegation. When the page loads, it's binds all events at that time to all elements that are executed and available in the DOM. Due to this behavior, replacing elements on the page will remove the previously bound events so to speak. It would be best to handle the elements in such a way that their events are bound to a static parent element that does not get replaced, and which the event can bubble up to.

That said, you've included the jQuery library, so all code will be focused on that, so we can stay cohesive:

```
jQuery(function($){ //setup the ready handler and alias the $ symbol as to not interfere
    //for the purpose of this example, our 'body' will be the static element.
    var $static = $('body');

    $static.on('click', 'textarea', function(){
        //the event is delegated, all textareas will receive this, present and future.
    });

    //again, we delegate the event to all forms present and future
    $static.on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(typeof(FormData) != 'undefined') {
            var oform = this;

            //a well supported method of file uploads using jQuery's Ajax and HTML5's FormData object.
            $.ajax({
                type: $(oform).prop('method'),
                url: $(oform).prop('action'),
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                data: new FormData(oform),
            }).on('success', function(resp){
                //do whatever on ajax success
            }).on('error', function(s,c,e){
                console.warn(s, c, e);
            });
        }
    });
});
```